How to Remove Landsat 7 Noise Lines From a Single Mean Image in GEE
I am trying to calculate an average NDVI layer from June through September 2011 using Landsat 7 data. I've been trying to remove the noise lines associated with Landsat 7 data after 2003 using data provided from a similar question. However, this does not seem to be cleaning up my lines. I think the issuse stems from the fact that the example code from the original solution removes the noise lines by first sorting all landsat images within the data by ascending cloud cover, and then selecting the first image in the data (.sort('CLOUD_COVER', true) .first()), which appears to remove all data from the noise lines, though I'm not entirely sure how. The missing data is then filled in using the focal_mean() and blend() functions.
I think my issue arises from the fact that I've already averaged the NDVI images together into a single image, so I can't use the sort() and first() functions to remove the noise lines from the image. Does this sound correct, and is there any way I can remvoe these noise lines from my single averaged NDVI layer? Thank you!
Here's a link to my code
EDIT: Ok, so I think I understand why the first() function removes the noise line data. The first function selects only the first image in the image collection, and since landsat 7 doesn't capture data from those noise line locations until after multiple passes, the noise lines are naturally left out from the image. My question then becomes, is there any way to remove these noise lines from my mean NDVI image, or is it impossible when using an image created from multiple images that results in data for those noise lines?
